# Lists - combine to give a new list

Tags: python, list

Python - lists:

For the following lists:

```
list_1=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14]
list_2=[3,8,1]
```

How do I combine these 2 lists to produce:

```
list_3=[3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Note that list_1 is missing runner number 5 and runner number 10 - this is deliberate.

In this example list_1 is a length of 12. list_1 represents the runners in a race.
list_2 represents which runner came in what position. So, runner 3 came first, runner 8 came second and runner 1 came third. list_3 has a length of 12 - and if the runner is not in the top three then that runner is designated '0'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me, in plain English, what the rule is for deciding what each value in `list_3` should be, one at a time? Can you talk me through, step by step, how you would do the calculation by hand? Either of those is the first step to writing correct code.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please show what you have tried so far and explain the specific problems you are having with it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question is: I want to make a list - in this case list_3.....which shows whether the runner came first, second or third. So - looking at list_3 in the question above, you can see that runner number 1 (from list_1) came third......so it is designated '3'.......runner number 2 (from list_1) didn't finish in the top 3....so it is designated a '0'....runner number 3(from list_1) came first.......so it is designated a '1'.......and so on....this is reflected in list_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a list comprehension and [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
list_3 = [list_2.index(x)+1 if x in list_2 and list_2.index(x) < 3 else 0 for x in list_1]
```

or shorter, since the rule *if the runner is not in the top three* is implicitly given through the length of `list_2`:

```
list_3 = [list_2.index(x)+1 if x in list_2 else 0 for x in list_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of the `.index()` method and give your lists/variables more meaningful names:

```
runners = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
result  = [3, 8, 1]

# desired output
list_3 = [3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

list3 = []
for runner in runners:
    try:
        list3.append(result.index(runner) + 1)
    except ValueError:
        list3.append(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over `list_2`

```
list_3 = [0]*len(list_1)
for i, pos in enumerate(list_2):
    ind = list_1.index(pos)
    list_3[ind] = i + 1
```